# How does telnet work?

Tags: network-access

I used telnet all the time to confirm ports are open and troubleshoot firewall issues, but how does it work? I thought that there is typically 1 service listening on 1 port (e.g., http listening on port 80, but it does not respond on any other port). How is it that the telnet service is listening on every port?

Comment: There are lots of explanations of telnet just a Google search away; you can't expect us to repeat it all here.  But briefly, when you telnet on port 80, you are talking to the http process, not telnet.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professional managed networks. This question seems to be more related to applications and how they function rather than a question about networks, even if they do use a network. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [su].

Comment: You may have misread the question. I believe the question is about TCP/IP ports in general, not about Telnet. The OP appears to assume that some kind of application protocol is negotiated with the initial handshake before the connection to a port is established, hence he's asking "How is ... listening on every port?". He probably just needs pointing out that you can point most TCP clients at any arbitrary port and the application protocol only comes into play at a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

As Ron Trunk pointed out, this is a subject which is too large to properly discuss here. The best place to start would be [RFC 854, TELNET PROTOCOL SPECIFICATION](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854).

> The TELNET Protocol is built upon three main ideas:  first, the
> concept of a "Network Virtual Terminal"; second, the principle of
> negotiated options; and third, a symmetric view of terminals and
> processes.
>
> 1. When a TELNET connection is first established, each end is    assumed to originate and terminate at a "Network Virtual Terminal",
>    or NVT.  An NVT is an imaginary device which provides a standard,
>    network-wide, intermediate representation of a canonical terminal.
>    This eliminates the need for "server" and "user" hosts to keep
>    information about the characteristics of each other's terminals and
>    terminal handling conventions.  All hosts, both user and server, map
>    their local device characteristics and conventions so as to appear to
>    be dealing with an NVT over the network, and each can assume a
>    similar mapping by the other party.  The NVT is intended to strike a
>    balance between being overly restricted (not providing hosts a rich
>    enough vocabulary for mapping into their local character sets), and
>    being overly inclusive (penalizing users with modest terminals).
>
> ```
>   NOTE:  The "user" host is the host to which the physical terminal
>   is normally attached, and the "server" host is the host which is
>   normally providing some service.  As an alternate point of view,
>   applicable even in terminal-to-terminal or process-to-process
>   communications, the "user" host is the host which initiated the
>   communication.
> ```
>
> 2. The principle of negotiated options takes cognizance of the fact    that many hosts will wish to provide additional services over
>    and    above those available within an NVT, and many users will have
>    sophisticated terminals and would like to have elegant, rather than
>    minimal, services.  Independent of, but structured within the TELNET
>    Protocol are various "options" that will be sanctioned and may be
>    used with the "DO, DON'T, WILL, WON'T" structure (discussed below) to
>    allow a user and server to agree to use a more elaborate (or perhaps
>    just different) set of conventions for their TELNET connection.  Such
>    options could include changing the character set, the echo mode, etc.
>
> The basic strategy for setting up the use of options is to have
> either party (or both) initiate a request that some option take
> effect.  The other party may then either accept or reject the
> request.  If the request is accepted the option immediately takes
> effect; if it is rejected the associated aspect of the connection
> remains as specified for an NVT.  Clearly, a party may always refuse
> a request to enable, and must never refuse a request to disable some
> option since all parties must be prepared to support the NVT.
>
> The syntax of option negotiation has been set up so that if both
> parties request an option simultaneously, each will see the other's
> request as the positive acknowledgment of its own.
>
> 3. The symmetry of the negotiation syntax can potentially lead to    nonterminating acknowledgment loops -- each party seeing the incoming
>    commands not as acknowledgments but as new requests which must be
>    acknowledged.  To prevent such loops, the following rules prevail:
>
> ```
>   a. Parties may only request a change in option status; i.e., a
>   party may not send out a "request" merely to announce what mode it
>   is in.
>
>   b. If a party receives what appears to be a request to enter some
>   mode it is already in, the request should not be acknowledged.
>   This non-response is essential to prevent endless loops in the
>   negotiation.  It is required that a response be sent to requests
>   for a change of mode -- even if the mode is not changed.
>
>   c. Whenever one party sends an option command to a second party,
>   whether as a request or an acknowledgment, and use of the option
>   will have any effect on the processing of the data being sent from
>   the first party to the second, then the command must be inserted
>   in the data stream at the point where it is desired that it take
>   effect.  (It should be noted that some time will elapse between
>   the transmission of a request and the receipt of an
>   acknowledgment, which may be negative.  Thus, a host may wish to
>   buffer data, after requesting an option, until it learns whether
>   the request is accepted or rejected, in order to hide the
>   "uncertainty period" from the user.)
> ```